# How to unpackage a DbSet<T> stored as an object without knowing its subtype at compile time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, casting

I have a `DbSet<T>`, where T is unknown at compile time, that is given to me from Reflection.  I would like to unpack it and work with the methods available to me in the non-generic `DbSet` Class.  However:

```
((DbSet)MyDbSetAsObject).Attach(MyValue); //InvalidCastException, can't cast from DbSet<T>to DbSet.
```

Am I missing something here?  this seems like a personally reasonable thing to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to retrieve a set for the given type.

```
var dbSet = MyContext.Set(MyType);
dbSet.Attach(MyValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic `DbSet<>` contains an implicit conversion to the non-generic `DbSet`:

```
// Summary:
//     Returns the equivalent non-generic System.Data.Entity.DbSet object.
//
// Returns:
//     The non-generic set object.
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2225:OperatorOverloadsHaveNamedAlternates", Justification = "Intentionally just implicit to reduce API clutter.")]
public static implicit operator DbSet(DbSet<TEntity> entry);
```

That means you can simply write:

```
DbSet nonGenericSet = myGenericSet;
```

You could also try (as already proposed by @Lorentz Vedeler):

```
DbSet nonGenericSet = this.Set(typeof(myRunTimeEntity));
```

Comment: I saw that.  Unfortunately, the whole problem stems from the fact that I was (Stupidly) getting `MeGenericSet` from Reflection (Specifically `Property.GetValue(MyContext)`), which results in an `Object`.  Thus the Implicit cast would not have worked.

I'm now getting my set the proper way, through the `Set()` method, rather than through Reflection.